# Drawing a line from a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I've been searching far and wide, but I haven't found a solution yet, so I'll ask here. I have a script that creates a large numpy array of coordinate points (~10^8 points), and i then want to draw a polygonal line using the coordinates. PIL's ImageDraw.line works fine for regular lists, but there seems to be a problem when using numpy arrays.

Right now this is my solution:

```
image = Image.new('RGB', (2**12, 2**12), 'black')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image, 'RGB')
draw.line(pos.tolist(), fill = '#00ff00')
```

where `pos` is the large numpy array that contains all points in the following order: `[x0, y0, x1, y1, ...]` (this can be changed if needed). The most time consuming part of the program is the `pos.tolist()` part, taking up about 75% of runtime.

Is there a way to draw a line and save it to an image and keeping it as a numpy array? I just want a simple image, nothing else besides the line and the black background.

Comment: See [How can I draw lines into numpy arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31638651/562769)

Comment: Have you already thought of simplifying the line  before drawing? Maybe a simple decimation (obviously considering the (x0,y0,x1,y1...) format) by 10 or 100 would speed up a lot your routine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list cast can be replaced with a float32 cast as follows

```
draw.line(pos.astype(np.float32), fill='#00ff00')
```

And you can get rid of casts in general if, when forming an array of points, you explicitly specify the type as `np.float32` for the array of points itself and all arrays with which it interacts, for example

```
pos = np.ones((2**8, 2), dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1)
pos *= np.random.randint(0, 2**12-1, size=(2**8, 2)).reshape(-1)
image = Image.new('RGB', (2**12, 2**12), 'black')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image, 'RGB')
draw.line(pos, fill='#00ff00')
```

should work fine.

Comment: I appreciate the effort made in answering a question I asked 8 years ago. Though I must admit that I'm not actively working with this code anymore.