# "Draw" a 3d line into an array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, 3d, geometry

I am looking for a solution do "draw" a 3d line (filled cylinder) into a 3d array using python just like the [skimage.draw.line](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.draw.html?highlight=draw#skimage.draw.line) function does for 2 arrays.

The line should have a starting point `(x1, y1, z1)`, an end point `(x2, y2, z2)`, and a radius `R`.

I had a look at [an example for a 2d line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638651/how-can-i-draw-lines-into-numpy-arrays/47381058#47381058) but I was not able to modify it to work in the 3d case.

I was thinking about drawing successive ellipses into the array, but I was not able to figure out how to calculate the two axes and the rotation angle.

Maybe there is a much simpler approach to this problem?

Comment: add some specs like how is your array defined . You need more info for this 2 points are not enough , you need also thickness or radius of the line take a look at this [LED Cube draw sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25135125/2521214) and [GLSL volumetric back raytracer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48092685/2521214) Do you want full volume or just the surface? btw I am sure I saw "exact" the same question here recently (may be 1-2 moths ago) with already working solution looking for better performance so try to find it (not sure what was the title and language however)

Comment: Thanks for the links, I will have a look! Yes, you would need to specify the radius `R`. Also the volume should be filled. I tried to find the question you mentioned, but I could not find it.

Comment: Maybe you thought of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638651/how-can-i-draw-lines-into-numpy-arrays?noredirect=1&lq=1 but this is only in 2d.

Comment: No that is not the one. I can not find it either (otherwise I would linked it) it was 3D using bresenham and wanted only the surface voxels and was concerning with the hole problem (which is not a case for fully filled volume) I added an Answer for you based on my volumetric back-ray-tracer ... I busted it for fun right now ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let assume this [GLSL volumetric back raytracer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48092685/2521214) as a start point. To make a filled **3D** line like this:

[image: overview]

You need:

1. **endpoints as spheres**

   see the `add_sphere` in the link above.
2. **discs cut at the endpoints**

   for that we need `U,V` basis vectors (perpendicular vectors to each other and to line itself). With those we can simply use any **2D** circle pixels acquisition and convert them to **3D** voxel positions with ease. So if `u,v` are coordinates in some **2D** circle centered at `(0,0)` then:

   ```
   x = x0 + u*U.x + v*V.x
   y = y0 + u*U.y + v*V.y
   z = z0 + u*U.z + v*V.z
   ```

   `(x,y,z)` are corresponding to **3D** circle voxel coordinate with center `(x0,y0,z0)`. For more info see [my C++ glCircle3D implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25182327/2521214).
3. **line body**

   As wee got all the voxel positions in the disc around `x0,y0,z0` endpoint of the line just cast a line from each of it with the same slope as line `(x0,y0,z0),(x1,y1,z1)` which are the endpoints of your line.

**When put together in C++ (sorry I do not code in python) I got this:**

```cpp
void volume::add_line(int x0,int y0,int z0,int x1,int y1,int z1,int r,GLuint col)
    {
    if (!_init) return;
    int i,n,x,y,z,cx,cy,cz,dx,dy,dz,kx,ky,kz;
    // endpoints are (half)spheres
    add_sphere(x0,y0,z0,r,col);
    add_sphere(x1,y1,z1,r,col);
    // DDA constants
    kx=0; dx=x1-x0; if (dx>0) kx=+1; if (dx<0) { kx=-1; dx=-dx; } dx++;           n=dx;
    ky=0; dy=y1-y0; if (dy>0) ky=+1; if (dy<0) { ky=-1; dy=-dy; } dy++; if (n<dy) n=dy;
    kz=0; dz=z1-z0; if (dz>0) kz=+1; if (dz<0) { kz=-1; dz=-dz; } dz++; if (n<dz) n=dz;
    // basis vectors
    double U[3],V[3],N[3]={x1-x0,y1-y0,z1-z0},u,v,rr=r*r;
    vector_one(N,N); // unit vector
    vector_ld(U,1.0,0.0,0.0); if (fabs(vector_mul(U,N))>=0.75) vector_ld(U,0.0,1.0,0.0); // |dot(U,N)|<0.75 means (1.0,0.0,0.0) is nearly parallel to N so chose (0.0,1.0,0.0) instead
    vector_mul(U,U,N); // U = U x N
    vector_mul(V,U,N); // V = U x N
    vector_one(U,U);   // U /= |U|
    vector_one(V,V);   // V /= |V|
    // disc
    for (u=-r;u<=+r;u++)
     for (v=-r;v<=+r;v++)
      if (u*u+v*v<=rr)
        {
        x=x0+double((u*U[0])+(v*V[0]));
        y=y0+double((u*U[1])+(v*V[1]));
        z=z0+double((u*U[2])+(v*V[2]));
        // DDA line
        for (cx=cy=cz=n,i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
            if ((x>=0)&&(x<size)&&(y>=0)&&(y<size)&&(z>=0)&&(z<size)) data[z][y][x]=col;
            cx-=dx; if (cx<=0) { cx+=n; x+=kx; }
            cy-=dy; if (cy<=0) { cy+=n; y+=ky; }
            cz-=dz; if (cz<=0) { cz+=n; z+=kz; }
            }
        }
    }
```

The `vector_xxx` functions are just my **3D** vector math and just dot,cross product and normalize to unit size are used which is easy to implement. You can see them here:

- [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

There are still things that can be improved like the spheres could be just half spheres and their generation can be joined with the disc stuff ... as the dot between normal and not offseted **3D** sphere coordinate is either positive/zero/negative which distinct endpoint half-sphere and disc ...  that would also fully eliminate the need for `U,V`.

Also depending on used **HW** and circumstances there might be also faster approaches like analytical (filling **BBOX** based on [distance from line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48303476/2521214)) if fast vector math is combined with massive parallelism like on **GPU**.

After some tweaking in my engine (added zoom and handle some accuracy problem) I got this result:

[image: objects]

for `128x128x128` volume inited like this:

```cpp
// init volume raytracer
vol.gl_init();
vol.beg();
int r,a,b,c;
r=10.0; a=r+1; b=vol.size-r-2; c=vol.size>>1;
                             //BBGGRR
vol.add_line(a,a,a,b,a,a,r,0x00FF2020);
vol.add_line(a,b,a,b,b,a,r,0x00FF2020);
vol.add_line(a,a,a,a,b,a,r,0x00FF2020);
vol.add_line(b,a,a,b,b,a,r,0x00FF2020);

vol.add_line(a,a,b,b,a,b,r,0x00FF2020);
vol.add_line(a,b,b,b,b,b,r,0x00FF2020);
vol.add_line(a,a,b,a,b,b,r,0x00FF2020);
vol.add_line(b,a,b,b,b,b,r,0x00FF2020);

vol.add_line(a,a,a,a,a,b,r,0x00FF2020);
vol.add_line(a,b,a,a,b,b,r,0x00FF2020);
vol.add_line(b,a,a,b,a,b,r,0x00FF2020);
vol.add_line(b,b,a,b,b,b,r,0x00FF2020);

vol.add_sphere(c,c,c,c>>1,0x00FF8040);
vol.add_sphere(a,c,c,r,0x004080FF);
vol.add_sphere(b,c,c,r,0x0080FF40);
vol.add_sphere(c,a,c,r,0x00FF4080);
vol.add_sphere(c,b,c,r,0x00AAAAAA);
vol.add_box(c,c,a,r,r,r,0x0060FF60);
vol.add_box(c,c,b,r,r,r,0x00FF2020);

vol.end();
```

Comment: Very nice solution! Thanks!

Comment: @user3637203 glad to be of help btw I added new screenshot how it looks like ....

Comment: Just a quick question: I am porting the code to python and you are using floats `x,y,z` to index `data`. What is the C++ behaviour there? Ceiling, Flooring or standard rounding?

Comment: @user3637203 the `x,y,z` are integers the only `float/doubles` are `u,v,U[3],V[3],N[3]` and `int=float` will `floor` the result

Comment: @user3637203 DDA line is much nicer (to code) than Bresenham and also faster on modern HW and also easily portable to any dimensionality as in gfx we sometimes want more than just 3D like [4D rendering techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44970550/2521214) or in industry I usually deal with `7-13` dimensional interpolation all the time ...

Comment: If I understand the code correctly, `vector_mul()` gives the cross product. But in one line you call `fabs(vector_mul(U,N))>=0.75`, so you compare the vector against a scalar? Or is it C++ magic, that `vector_mul()` sometimes gives the dot product and sometimes the cross product?

Comment: @user3637203 `double vector_mul(double *a,double *b)` return dot product `(a.b)` and `void vector_mul(double c,double a,double b)` is cross product `c=a x b`. I added some comments into the code to make more sense from it

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to implement this in python using skimage.draw.ellipse:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm
import skimage.draw

c = lambda *x: np.array(x, dtype=float)
vector_angle = lambda V, U: np.arccos(norm(np.dot(V, U)) / (norm(V) + norm(U)))

r = 10 # radius of cylinder
C0 = c(10, 10, 10) # first (x,y,z) point of cylinder
C1 = c(99, 90, 15) # second (x,y,z) point of cylinder

C = C1 - C0

X, Y, Z = np.eye(3)

theta = vector_angle(Z, C)
print('theta={} deg'.format(theta / np.pi * 180))

minor_axis = r
major_axis = r / np.cos(theta)
print('major_axis', major_axis)

alpha = vector_angle(X, C0 + C)
print('alpha={} deg'.format(alpha / np.pi * 180))

data = np.zeros([100, 100, 100])
nz, ny, nx = data.shape

for z in range(nz):
    lam = - (C0[2] - z)/C[2]
    P = C0 + C * lam
    y, x = skimage.draw.ellipse(P[1], P[0], major_axis, minor_axis, shape=(ny, nx), rotation=alpha)
    data[z, y, x] = 1
```

Comment: Is this also possible without the cylinder stuff, so that i just have a 3d line between two points? Best regards!

Comment: And what is about edges if you draw a line from a to b and b to c, and there is a a crinkle?