# Check if a 3D Point lies on a given 3D line(between two 3D Points)

Tags: c#, c++, graphics, geometry

I have two 3D Points viz. (x1,y1,z1) and (x2,y2,z2) and a 3D Point (x,y,z).
I would like to know if (x,y,z) lies on the line connecting (x1,y1,z1) and (x2,y2,z2).

I tried the following algorithm:

```
    if ((((x - x1) / x2-x1) == ((y - y1) / y2-y1)) && (((x - x1) / x2 - x1) 
== ((z - z1) / z2- z1)) --> then,the 3D Line intersects (x,y,z)
```

But,what if my x1 = x2 (or) y1 = y2 (or) z1=z2? Then I would be getting an error saying "Division by zero" is not possible.

I would be glad,if someone can propose some alternative method.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

simple dot product can do this easily ... so let consider we got **line** defined by two points `p0,p1`. Any point `p` on that **line** will have the same or negative slope to any of the endpoints so

```
|dot(p1-p0,p-p0)|/(|p1-p0|*|p-p0|) = 1.0
```

to make it more robust with floating point compare like this:

```
|dot(p1-p0,p-p0)|/(|p1-p0|*|p-p0|) >= 1.0-1e-10;
```

Where `1e-10` is small enough epsilon ... rewriten to code:

```
dx=x1-x0;
dy=y1-y0;
dz=z1-z0; 

ex=x-x0;
ey=y-y0;
ez=z-z0;

q =dx*ex;
q+=dy*ey;
q+=dz*zy;
q*=q;
q/=(dx*dx+dy*dy+dz*dz);
q/=(ex*ex+ey*ey+ez*ez);

if (q>=1.0-1e-10) point p(x,y) is on the line
 else p(x,y) is not on line
```

As you can see no need for the sqrt we can compare the power instead ...

However you should handle edge case when `p==p0` then either use `p1` or return true right away.

In case you want points only inside the **line segment** (not outside the edge points) then you need a slight change in code

```
0.0 <= dot(p1-p0,p-p0)/|p-p0| <= 1.0
```

So:

```
dx=x1-x0;
dy=y1-y0;
dz=z1-z0; 

ex=x-x0;
ey=y-y0;
ez=z-z0;

q =dx*ex;
q+=dy*ey;
q+=dz*zy;
if (q<0.0) p(x,y) is not on line
q*=q;
q/=(ex*ex+ey*ey+ez*ez);

if (q<=1.0) point p(x,y) is on the line
 else p(x,y) is not on line
```

btw the result of the dot product gives you ratio of one vector projected to another perpendicularly or cos of the angle between them (if they are normalized) so for parallel vectors the result is `100%` of length or `1.0`. If you tweak the `1e-10` value using goniometry and `p-p0` you can convert this to detect points up to some perpendicular distance to line (which might get handy for thick lines and or mouse selecting).

Answer (score 1):

I would use [point-line distance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html) measurement, and return true if the distance is less than some error threshold close to zero.

To elaborate, we are using a line made of two points, `p1` and `p2`. We want to know if `p3` is on the line. First we find `d` using the point-to-line distance formula.

`d = ((p0 - p1).cross(p0 - p2)).length() / (p2 - p1).length()`

That is, assuming you can use `+`, `-`, `cross`, `length` operations. You might prefer to find `d` squared for performance reasons.

`d2 = ((p0 - p1).cross(p0 - p2)).lengthSquared() / (p2 - p1).lengthSquared()`

Now, if `d` or `d2` are exactly zero, then you *must* be on the line. But this is floating point arithmetic so I would allow a little bit of leeway depending on your application. So in essence, `d < 1e6` or something should do the trick.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your algorithm?

Comment: @Exploring_Programming Done.

Comment: but would n't that be risky? Suppose all my points are decimals,upto some 6 digits, Then, If we keep some condition,such as d < 1e6, would n't that be taking into account,additional points too,which are not lying on the line?

Comment: @Exploring_Programming Are you aware that floating point numbers resulting from a computation can never reliable be compared for exact equality? See [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: @Exploring_Programming Yes you are correct. But it also risky to assume that it will be exactly zero as Angew says. Make sure that the threshold is very small and close enough to zero that you don't count any point that is close to the line but not on it.

Answer (score 0):

As you yourself point out, doing this in a robust way is not trivial. Therefore, I suggest you don't reinvent the wheel and use a geometric library. I have good experience with using [Wild Magic from geometrictools.com](https://www.geometrictools.com/).

In your case, the predicate to use would be [`gte::DCPQuery`](https://www.geometrictools.com/GTEngine/Include/Mathematics/GteDistPointLine.h) to get the distance between a point and the line, and then test if it's close enough to zero for your purpose of "on the line."

An example of use could look like this:

```
using namespace gte;

Line3<double> line({x1, y1, z1}, {x2 - x1, y2 - y1, z2 - z1});
Vector3<double> point{x, y, z};

DCPPoint3Line3 query;
auto result = query(point, line);
bool pointIsOnLine = (result.distance < some_epsilon);
```

(Code note touched by compiler, intended to show the approach, not to be "semicolon-perfect").

Comment: I am doing this in C# as of now. Can you please elaborate this algorithm in C# please?

Comment: @Exploring_Programming The question is tagged both C# and C++, so I assumed an answer in either is fine.

Comment: yes,even C++ Would do. Could you elaborate the usage of gte::DCPQuery, so that I can use it

Comment: @Exploring_Programming Added example.

Comment: Is it advisable to take, some_epsilon around 1e-6?

Comment: @Exploring_Programming That's roughly the value I would reach for by default, yes. It depends on your application and the range of numbers you normally deal with, though.

Comment: Been trying to implement your algorithm in C#, But I could not find any class called Line3 there. Could you check it once in C#

Comment: @Exploring_Programming I'm a C++ programmer, I know precious little about C#. But the entire source code of Wild Magic is available at the site I linked, and if you're doing geometry, you should be able to make sense of it and port it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the above-mentioned problem you need to check the area of the triangle considering them as 3 points in the 3-d space. To find the area go through this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnpaeFPyn1A). If area = 0 then given points are collinear.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

if you are not concerned about performance issue you can use the parametric equation of a segment in the space.

`P(t) = P0 + t(P1 - P0)`
where P0 and P1 are 3d point and t is a parameter ranging from 0 to 1.

this lead to 3 equations

```
x(t) = x0 + t(x1 - x0)
y(t) = y0 + t(y1 - y0)
z(t) = z0 + t(z1 - z0)
```

so to check if your (x,y,z) point lies in the line, you could get an initial value for t, for example **`t = (x - x0)/(x1-x0)`** then check if that satisfies the other two equations

```
t = (x - x0)/(x1-x0)

if ( (y0 + t(y1-y0) == y) and (z0 + t(z1-z0) == z) ) then
 ---> we are in the line
```

Like @Jay pointed out, this is floating point math you have to deal with some tolerance with values. For example to test y could be *y0 + t(y1-y0) - y < 0.001*